# MediaContentProvider not working with SMS App (but with WhatsApp, Email, ...)

Tags: android, cursor, android-contentprovider

Following `MediaContentProvider` (a simple image file provider) is working correctly with all types of apps, but not with my SMS (or better MMS) app.

I know, the SMS app is expecting a `Cursor` instead of a `ParcelFileDescriptor`, does this mean I have to save my image file to a database and retrieve it from there? Or is there a better solution for that?

```
public class MediaContentProvider extends ContentProvider
{
public static final String AUTHORITY = "MEDIA";

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreate()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
{
    return 0;
}

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    return pfd;
}
```

}

**EDIT**

as suggested, here my `FileProvider`... Actually, it results in the same behaviour... As I said, I think I have to somehow provide a cursor for the SMS app...

```
public class ImageFileProvider extends FileProvider
{
public static final String AUTHORITY = "ImageFileProvider";

@Override
public ParcelFileDescriptor openFile(Uri uri, String mode) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String fileName = uri.getLastPathSegment();
    ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = ParcelFileDescriptor.open(new File(getContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName), ParcelFileDescriptor.MODE_READ_ONLY);
    return pfd;
}
```

}

Comment: What does "not with my SMS (or better MMS) app" mean? BTW, you may be better served [using `FileProvider` for this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), as it is already written and in the Android Support package.

Comment: it fails... SMS app says something like "you can't add this to your message" and opens an empty sms... but I'll take a look at the `FileProvider`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be expecting you to support `OpenableColumns` in your `query()` method.

It may be needing you to grant it permission to access the data, as your `ContentProvider` should be appropriately secured.

It certainly is expecting you to return a real MIME type from `getType()`, rather than `null`.

I still [recommend `FileProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html), but if you want to roll something yourself, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/GrantUriPermissions) has the basics.

Comment: You did not follow the instructions properly for using `FileProvider`. You don't subclass it, for example. Here is a complete sample app demonstrating the use of `FileProvider`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider

Comment: OK, now it works as expected, even with the SMS app. Thanks a lot